# define alias for gradle task with custom argument

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, gradlew, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I want to run

`./gradlew extractMyDeps`

instead of

`./gradlew :app:dependencies --configuration productionDebugRuntimeClasspath`

**but I can't pass args to this task via `dependOn`**

How to achieve my goal?

```
task("extractMyDeps") {
    dependsOn(":app:dependencies") // how pass --configuration
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't pass the command line arguments to another task. But if you want to make an alias for a task you can use [Exec Tasks](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec.html) like this:

```
task('extractMyDeps', type: Exec) {
    workingDir '..'

    def arguments = ['cmd', '/c', 'gradlew', ':app:dependencies', '--configuration', 'testCompileClasspath']

    commandLine arguments
}
```

By using this task, you can run:

`> gradlew extractMyDeps`

Also you can make it more dynamic by passing the configuration name like this:

```
task('extractMyDeps', type: Exec) {
    workingDir '..'
    def arguments = ['cmd', '/c', 'gradlew', ':app:dependencies']
    if (project.hasProperty("conf")) {
        def conf = project.property("conf")
        arguments.add('--configuration')
        arguments.add(conf.toString())
    }

    commandLine arguments
}
```

This way these commands are valid:

`> gradlew extractMyDeps`

`> gradlew extractMyDeps -Pconf=testCompileClasspath`

I hope it will help you.